# Numbering lines in an document

Tags: line-numbering

I wanna set some numbers at the end of an line but dont know how?

Dont just wanna number some equations (for that i use "align") but in an text, if there is an important statement i wanna refer to later, just wanna set a number at the end of the line.

thankfull for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `lineno` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\begin{document}

\begin{linenumbers}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. 
Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent
imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, 
lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus
nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent 
in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero \linelabel{myline} ** label here **
ut metus. Pellentesque
placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis
sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet
aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum.
Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.
\end{linenumbers}

This is the line having number \ref{myline}.
\end{document}
```

[image]